# Django - AttributeError at / 'function' object has no attribute 'objects'

Tags: python, django

I been getting this error. I dont know why my view and model names are different still im getting that error in django.

This is my models.py

```
from django.db import models

class data(models.Model):
   id = models.IntegerField(default=1, unique=True, primary_key=True)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   location = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   date = models.DateField()

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'datas'

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

This is my views.py

```
from appplus.models import data

def dashboard(request):
   last_added = data.objects.order_by('date')[:5]
   context_dict = {
    'last_added' : last_added
   }
return render(request, 'appplus/home.html', context_dict)
```

Comment: likely you have a view named `data` in your `views.py`...

Comment: Could you share your ```views.py``` entirely? Additionally, try to name your models capitalized.